# Does completing a handler promise affect Vert.x's blocking thread checker?

Tags: vert.x

I am writing a hello world vert.x program to try and understand its threading model. I am not able to explain the output I am seeing however.

The design of the code is as follows:

- The 'Main' class instantiates the 'Mothership' verticle, waits for 10 seconds and then closes Vertx
- The 'Mothership' verticle instantiates the 'Sentinel' verticle

Main.java

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Vertx vertx = Vertx.factory.vertx();
        ID vertxID = new ID(UUID.randomUUID(), "Vertx Oracle");


        Mothership mothership = new Mothership();
          vertx.deployVerticle(mothership).setHandler(ParentVerticle.asyncResultHandler(vertxID,  "Mothership online!", "Could not instantiate the mother ship!"));

        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
        vertx.close();
        logger.info("Closed vertx");
    }
```

Mothership.java (extends ParentVerticle.java)

```java
public Mothership() {
        super("Mothership");
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Promise<Void> startPromise) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Mothership has come into being with ID: " + id);
        vertx.deployVerticle(new Sentinel()).setHandler(ParentVerticle.asyncResultHandler(id, "Mothership gave birth to a sentinel","Could not give birth to a sentinel!"));
        startPromise.complete();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop(Promise<Void> stopPromise) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Mothership powered down! ID: " + id);
    }
```

Sentinel.java (extends ParentVerticle.java)

```java
public Sentinel() {
        super("Sentinel");
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Promise<Void> startPromise) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Sentinel alive! ID: " + id);
        startPromise.complete();
    }

    @Override
    // Perform cleanup here
    public void stop(Promise<Void> stopPromise) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Sentinel powered down! ID: " + id);
    }
```

Helper objects:
ID.java

```java
public UUID id;
    public String machineType;

    public ID(UUID id, String machineType) {
        this.id = id;
        this.machineType = machineType;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ID{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", machineType='" + machineType + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
```

ParentVehicle.java (extends AbstractVerticle.java)

```java
 ParentVerticle(String machineType) {
        this.id = new ID(UUID.randomUUID(), machineType);
    }

    public static <T> Handler<AsyncResult<T>> asyncResultHandler(ID receiverID, String successResult, T alternateResult) {
        return asyncResult -> {
            StringJoiner builder = new StringJoiner("\n");
            builder.add(String.format("\nResult of an asynchronous operation received by: %s, %s ", receiverID.id, receiverID.machineType));

            if (asyncResult.failed()) {
                builder.add("Failed verticle result: ");
                builder.add(asyncResult.cause().getMessage());
                builder.add("Alternate value: " + asyncResult.otherwise(alternateResult).result());
            } else {
                builder.add(successResult);
                builder.add("Success result: " + asyncResult.result());
            }

            logger.info(builder.add("\n").toString());
        };
    }
}
```

The output of the program is as follows:

```sh
[2019-09-27 15:34:05,400] [INFO] [c.t.v.v.Mothership  ] [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] Mothership has come into being with ID: ID{id=11078768-3bb3-4ef1-90a5-5e7cd4902b22, machineType='Mothership'}
[2019-09-27 15:34:05,404] [INFO] [c.t.v.v.Sentinel    ] [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] Sentinel alive! ID: ID{id=44b74ee8-fb95-435c-9b50-aab3ad0a6dae, machineType='Sentinel'}
[2019-09-27 15:34:05,406] [INFO] [c.t.v.v.ParentVerticle] [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] 
Result of an asynchronous operation received by: 11078768-3bb3-4ef1-90a5-5e7cd4902b22, Mothership 
Mothership gave birth to a sentinel
Success result: bed61628-e728-40fb-89eb-12d3d174a7f0


[2019-09-27 15:34:05,406] [INFO] [c.t.v.v.ParentVerticle] [vert.x-eventloop-thread-2] 
Result of an asynchronous operation received by: 356e3b9a-0c3d-4888-9f5a-8132957d3b5a, Vertx Oracle 
Mothership online!
Success result: 01dc7fa4-274e-407d-82a1-8b1d0c58ab0a


[2019-09-27 15:34:15,407] [INFO] [c.t.v.Main          ] [main] Closed vertx
[2019-09-27 15:34:15,410] [INFO] [c.t.v.v.Sentinel    ] [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] Sentinel powered down! ID: ID{id=44b74ee8-fb95-435c-9b50-aab3ad0a6dae, machineType='Sentinel'}
```

Questions:

- The program never terminates though. A thread dump shows  a "Vertx-blocked-thread-checker" in a "TIMED_WAITING" state. Why?
- While the Sentinel's stop method is called, the Mothership's stop method is never called. Why?
- If I do not complete the promise in the "Mothership" class, the program terminates but neither the Mothership nor the Sentinel power down. Why?

Comment: Most of your problems are due to the fact that you're probably blocking the vertx thread with the sleep. You should use `vertx.setTimer(10000, t -> vertx.close());` instead

Comment: And when you don't complete the promise in the start method, the deployment never finishing, and therefore you won't see the stop being called.

Comment: Isn't that the Main thread? The log line that prints "Closed vertx" indicates that the thread is "main".

Comment: [Here](https://pastebin.com/5RemL9X2) is a thread stack of the application after Vert.x has closed. As far I can see, the Vertx blocker checker thread is a daemon and should not block the application from exiting.